# Show $\phi(x) = (x - x_1)(x - x_2) \cdots (x - x_m)$ is odd for $m$ odd.

Tags: functions

Given the function
$$
   \phi(x) = (x - x_1) (x - x_2) \cdots (x - x_m)
$$
where $m$ is odd, and the points $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m$ are symmetric wrt the midpoint of its domain, show that the function is odd wrt the midpoint of its domain. We define
$$
a \le x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_m \le b
$$
so that the midpoint of its domain $[a, b]$ is $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

---

What we can do is define a transform $$ \tau = x - \frac{a + b}{2}$$ that recentres the domain onto $$ \left[\frac{a - b}{2}, \frac{b - a}{2}\right] $$ which has midpoint the origin.

It remains to show that $$ \phi(-\tau) = -\phi(\tau). $$

---

I understand the function should be odd, but I can't show this algebraically. I've tried using induction on $m$, but if $m=1$ then
$$ -\phi(\tau) = -(\tau - x_1),$$
$$ \phi(-\tau) = (-\tau - x_1),$$
and I can't even prove the base case.
I've also tried just substituting in $\tau$ and $-\tau$ for arbitrary odd $m$ and doing some algebra but I only get
$$ -\phi(\tau) = - (\tau - x_1) (\tau - x_2) \cdots (\tau - x_m),$$
$$ \phi(-\tau) = - (\tau + x_1) (\tau + x_2) \cdots (\tau + x_m).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $m = 2k + 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. Then if $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{2k+1}$ are symmetric wrt the origin, it follows that we can relabel these $2k + 1$ roots as:
$$
-r_k,~ -r_{k-1},~ \ldots,~ -r_1,~ 0,~ r_1,~ \ldots,~ r_{k-1},~ r_k
$$